# SwiftUI: Is there a way to collapse only one button on click and not all of them

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I added three buttons inside the scroll view and I want to get the effect when a user clicks a button - that only that button is clicked and not every one of the buttons, so that the hidden description appears only on the clicked button.

[image: Buttons without description]

[image: Buttons with description]

And code:

```
struct WordCells: View {
    @State private var toggleView = false
    var numberOfItems = Int.init()
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 40.0) {
                ForEach(0..<self.numberOfItems) {item in
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                            self.toggleView.toggle()
                       }
                   })
                   {
                    VStack {
                       HStack {
                            Text("Button Text")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.callout)

                            Spacer()

                            Text("Description")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.customLabel)
                                .font(.callout)
                            }
                        if self.toggleView {
                            HiddenDescriptionView()
                        }
                       }
                       .frame(width: geometry.size.width/1.3)
                   }

                   .padding(23.0)
                   .background(Color.white)

               }
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32))
                .shadow(color: .customLabel, radius: 15)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an array of Boolean so that you can track the expanded state of each button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct WordCells: View {
    @State private var toggleView: Int? = nil  // << selection
    var numberOfItems = Int.init()
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 40.0) {
                ForEach(0..<self.numberOfItems) {item in
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                            if self.toggleView == item { // << here !!
                                self.toggleView = nil
                            } else {
                                self.toggleView = item
                            }
                       }
                   })
                   {
                    VStack {
                       HStack {
                            Text("Button Text")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.callout)

                            Spacer()

                            Text("Description")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .font(.callout)
                            }
                        if self.toggleView == item { // << selection !!
                            HiddenDescriptionView()
                        }
                       }
                       .frame(width: geometry.size.width/1.3)
                   }

                   .padding(23.0)
                   .background(Color.white)

               }
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32))
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 15)
           }
        }
    }
}
```